# Magento 1.7 After (or before) cart update get old and new quotes of each product

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying really hard to learn Magento, but I need some help.

I want to track product quotes changes in cart after clicking to "update cart" button. I found nice events called **checkout_cart_update_items_after** and **checkout_cart_update_items_before**. But I don't know how to get info about cart quotes changes in observer.

The best I achieved was

```
public function Mytestupd($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getData('cart');
    $quote = $product->getData('quote');
    $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

    foreach($items as $item) {
        $prsku .= $item->getQty()." ";
    } 
    }
```

Which of course just gives me old (or new, depends on event) quote of each item.
At the end I'd like to do

```
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess("Cart Updated, your changes are: ".$changes);
```

where $changes is something like
"productOne: 3 items added; productTwo: 4 items removed"

I hope I was clear enough and someone will help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's great to have session variables. So I could do

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCartItems($myVals);
```

in `checkout_cart_update_items_before` event Observer and later do

```
$oldcart = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCartItems();
```

in `checkout_cart_update_items_after` event Observer

Comment: `checkout_cart_update_items_after` does not fire from backend. Is there any event which work for both frontend and backend.